# Interaction term (OLS) interpretation

Tags: interaction, least-squares

How should I interpret interaction term in OLS?

Dummy: 0 is flat tax system, 1 is progressive one.

Cont: continuous variable ranges from -2.5 to 2.5.

Before interaction:

> dummy |  .0183619   .0166824     1.10   0.278
>
> cont  |  .0616873   .0110176     5.60   0.000

After interaction:

> dummy |  -.0429928   .0201104    -2.14   0.039
> cont  |   .0301204   .0118294     2.55   0.015
> inter |   .0784644   .0186501     4.21   0.000

What are possible explanations for the dummy turning negative?

Comment: What do the numbers mean?

Comment: Please, try ti improve formatting, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first column is the coefficient value, the second one is
standard error, and thereafter are $t$ and $p$ values.

Before: dummy is close to 0.  This means that flat/progressive tax
system has little effect (no relationship to causality ;-)  after
controlling for the continuous variable (call it $x$).

After: dummy is -0.043 and significant.  In case the dummy = 0, you
just ignore the interaction (it is always zero) and you just look at
the $x$ estimate.  For observations where dummy is 1, you have to add
the interaction term and the $x$ estimate, and you get $-0.043 + 0.078
+ 0.030 = 0.065$.  If $x = -1$ you get the tax system effect analogously
$-0.043 - 0.078 - 0.030 = -0.151$.

The fact that insignificant dummy turns negative when you add
interaction has rather simple intuition:

- Before, you assume that both cases (dummy = 0 and dummy = 1) have a
  common slope ($x$ coefficient) but different intercepts
- Afterwards, you allow both slopes and intercepts to differ.
  Obviously, changing slope will most likely change intercept too
  unless the slope line "turns around" $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interpret them without also looking at the intercept. It might be that dummy + intercept is still positive. But think about it this way: perhaps the two groups (flat vs progressive system) have widely different effects of the continuous variable. Think of the effect as a function over -2.5 to 2.5. Then the dummy shifts that line up and down while the cont coefficient is the slope parameter. One of the lines can either shift up or down relative to the other (the dummy coefficient) or its slope can change (the cont coefficient).